# how to use if(math.random == 50)?

Tags: javascript, math, random

So i am trying to make a site that picks a random number and if that number is between for example 50-60 it is going to do something

Here is some code:

```
var opengg;
window.onload = function() {
    opengg = function() {
    console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
    if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) == 50) {
            console.log("test")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is exactly the question you are asking here?

Comment: Like this, it will never do anything, put your code out of the opengg function

Comment: FYI: The console log generates one number while the if statement generates another number....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)` twice, use it only once because every time it will generate a new number and assign it to a variable & check if that is between 50 & 60. The result of `Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)` inside `console.log();` & `if ()` is very unlikely to be equal. So even if you see the number logs is in the range but rarely it will be the same number inside the `if`'s conditional statement

```js
let opengg = function() {
  let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  console.log(num)
  if (num >= 50 && num <= 60) {
    console.log("test")
  }
}

opengg();
```